# How to make the page load to an anchor tag?

Tags: tags, anchor

how could I, or is it possible, to make it so when the webpage loads, the first thing it shows you is the part of the page, where the anchor tag is you want the person to first see.

Is it possible?

Thanks for all help in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Something simple like this would do it

```
<body onload=' location.href="#myanchor" '>
<a id='myanchor' href='#'>anchor text</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a 2018 update that's a bit more dynamic.

If you'd like to pull the URL, pull the anchor from the URL, and move the page to that anchor, you can run this javascript on page load.

```js
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') == 0) {
        let hash = window.location.href.split('#')[1];
        let hashTop = document.querySelector(`#${hash}`).offsetTop;
        window.scrollTop = hashTop;
    }
```

There's also this way which is a bit more concise.

```js
    if (location.hash) {
        let target = location.hash;
        window.scrollTop = document.querySelector(target).offsetTop;
    }
```

If you're not compiling ES6 with babel, just change the `let` keyword to `var`. This also works for WordPress, which will add a slash in the URL before the anchor.

Answer (score 7):

Use javascript.

**Solution 1**

When the document loads, go to the "hash" or anchor that you want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
window.location.hash="mylocation"; 
}
</script>
```

**Solution 2**

In the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function moveWindow (){window.location.hash="mylocation";}
</script>
```

On the body tag:

```
<body onload="moveWindow()">
```

And your anchor:

`<a name="mylocation"></a`>

Comment: Thank you very much! I needed a way to set an anchor in the Twig URL to go to a specific spot on the page if an exception is thrown. Can't be done, so instead, I put a twig variable in the body tag and set it to an empty string. Then, if the exception is thrown, I populate the string variable with javascript, as shown in your answer (window.location.hash="foo"), and add it to the render of the page: <body {{ anchor | raw }}>.

Answer (score 0):

A mix of these answers turned out to be the best option for me and has the advantage of being dynamic by pulling from the anchor from the URL and forcing the page to load at the intended destination:

```
if (location.hash) location.href = location.hash;
```

This was the cleanest solution for my project due to a number of other things running onload:

JQuery:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    if (location.hash) location.href = location.hash;
}
```

Vanilla:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (location.hash) location.href = location.hash;
}
```

Comment: Closing bracket is missing after curly braces. Instead of } use }). Also it does not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Jake Scott’s answer worked for me, finally.
And if anybody is a noob like me, make sure to place it in your head tag, maybe right above the closing tag, and copy the full script from below with tags (I wish people would take the consideration to do that, for us noobs who need the exact details).

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
       if (location.hash) location.href = location.hash;
    });
</script>
```