# Redirect back not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-blade, back

I am just doing a project in which I want to redirect back on to another tab. I am stuck in this as it doesnot working fully. I cannot redirect another tab as it redirect back to the default tab. How can I do this.
My view is

```
<div class="nav-tab  clearfix">
                                <div class="nav-tab-item active">
                                    <span>Intro</span>
                                </div>
                                @if ( Auth::check() )
                                    @if ( $user->id == Auth::user()->id )
                                        <div id="Appointments" class="nav-tab-item tab-pane {{ !empty($tabName) && $tabName == 'Appointments' ? 'active' : '' }}">

                                            <span>Appointments</span>
                                            <span class="ribbon" style="display: none">02</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="nav-tab-item ">
                                            <span>Calendar</span>
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                                <div class="nav-tab-item ">
                                    <span>Reviews</span>
                                </div>
                                @if ( Auth::check() )
                                    @if ( $user->id == Auth::user()->id )
                                        <div class="nav-tab-item " id="tab5">
                                            <span>Billing</span>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="nav-tab-item">
                                            <span>Payment History</span>
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                @endif

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

My redirect method is

```
return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#Appointments");
```

plz help me guys.

Comment: Does it return the proper url with the given anchor tag?

Comment: Yes it does @Neat

Comment: If i remember correctly, the anchor tag doesnt "open" the right tab without handling it yourself on page load, You might wanna check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368129/how-to-make-the-page-load-to-an-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 0):

I read document homepage laravel. I think it can help you!

Redirecting To The Previous URL

You may wish to redirect the user to their previous location, for example, after a form submission. You can do so by using the back method:

```
return redirect()->back();
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

You refe link to: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects and https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html#method_back

**I hope help you!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return redirect()->to(url()->previous()."#Appointments");
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Hey If you are using laravel 5.2 or greater version than you dont need to write

```
Redirect::back()
```

You can simply use `back()` helper function to do this.

so you can replace your code with below code.

```
return back()
```

Here is a link for [back() helper function documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-back).