# Linking to a specific div of another page; can only link to that div whilst on that page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a link

```
<a href="about.html#div2">Click me</a>
```

When I click the link I am brought to `about.html` at the top of the document.

If I am already visiting about.html and and I type `about.html#div2` in the search bar of my browser(chrome), then my browser goes down to the specific div(div2).

How can I get my browser to visit the div on the other page from the link on another page.

I am also using react, if that makes a difference

---

**Update**

So right now I have a link on index.html that is

```
<a href="about.html#div2">Click me</a>
```

and on about.html I have

```
<a id="div2" name="div2"></a>
```

on about.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is anchor tags which some pages make use of to link to specific sections on pages. This is done by [setting anchor tags](https://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html) on the page. What you are referring to is slightly different. The tags are instead being used by Javascript to load a specific element. These are usually added to the URL when elements are clicked on that load a section.

These are usually triggered on click to display the content requested. What is also needed is code that also looks at the URL that is loaded and properly loads in those elements, as if they were clicked. Right now it sounds like you have nothing that is handling this and it's only being handled when an element is clicked.

Comment: What would be an example of code that looks at the url loaded and properly load in those elements

Comment: Good examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368129/how-to-make-the-page-load-to-an-anchor-tag @Jacob